# When is stringbuf::flush called?

Tags: c++, synchronization, stringbuffer, std

```
struct encrypt_stream : public std::stringbuf
{
    int sync() { encrypt_buffer(); flush_to_device(); }
    ...
private:
    void encrypt_buffer();
    void flush_to_device();
};
```

I want to write this class to encrypt text data. Every time this `stringbuf` object is flushed, `sync` is called and an encrypted version of the buffer is sent to the device. The encrypted text strongly depends on the moment when `flush` is called. Are there tricky cases where `flush` can be called on this object without the user asking for it?

I know that `flush` is called when `std::endl` is received, but are there any other cases I am unaware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`flush()` is called in these situations:

- When `std::endl` is used (namely an explicit call to `std::ostream::flush()`) [§27.7.3.7/7]
- When the stream's destructor is called [§27.5.3.1.6/4]
- When the stream to which it is `tie()`-ed performs a read. [§27.7.2.1.3/2]
- When the file stream is repositioned.
- When the stream has reached the maximum allocated characters in its buffer, when `overflow()` is called to extract the content to the external device, [§27.6.3.4.5/3]
- or in the case of input streams, when `gptr() == egptr()`, a call to `underflow()` to discard the content and synchronize its buffer with the external device. [§27.6.3.4.3/7]

This is what I know about the standard IOStreams. This could vary depending on the implementation of your stream or stream buffer.

Comment: Good, but _[citation needed]_

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm on the hunt as we speak. :)